# Convert MySQL with Subqueries to DQL 1.2

Tags: mysql, subquery, dql

Hi I have the following query from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839326/mysql-query-or-doctrine-1-2-query-get-most-recent-item-from-joined-table-and) and need to convert it to DQL for Doctrine 1.2. However it turns out that DQL does not support subqueries in joins.

```
SELECT * FROM contact c
  LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT a1.contact_id, a1.date, a1.activity_type_id FROM activity a1
      JOIN (SELECT contact_id, MAX(DATE) DATE FROM activity GROUP BY contact_id) a2
        ON a1.contact_id = a2.contact_id AND a1.date = a2.date
     ) a
  ON c.id = a.contact_id  

WHERE a.activity_type_id = 2;
```

I'm trying to figure out how to do this another way without resorting to multiple queries.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a view instead of a subquery?

Comment: I have never used a view but doctrine appears to support them.

Comment: I have read about views in doctrine and it wont solve it for me.. I am going to have to try and rewrite this as a DQL query but I don't know if it is possible to do it.

Comment: So, can you for instance create a view `CREATE VIEW max_activity_date AS SELECT contact_id, MAX(date) AS max_date FROM activity GROUP BY contact_id` and join to that?

Comment: I managed to rewrite it. Views didn't work but was able to do it  different way. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final query:

```
SELECT * FROM contact c
    LEFT JOIN activity ON c.id = contact_id
    WHERE ROW (c.id,DATE) IN (SELECT contact_id, MAX(date) date FROM activity  GROUP BY contact_id)
    AND activity_type_id = 2
```

Final DQL:

```
$q->from('Contact c') 
->leftJoin('c.Activity a')      
->where('ROW (c.id, date) IN (SELECT a1.contact_id, MAX(a1.date) a1.date FROM Activity a1 GROUP BY a1.contact_id)')
->andWhere('a.activity_type_id = ?', $filterActivityTypeId);
```

Answer (score 3):

Using doctrine, you should not nest subqueries into where condition using raw sql. You will get into trouble in more complex scenarios. Instead use `createSubquery` to explicitly tell doctrine about the subquery, let doctrine compile it to DQL and then nest it into your where condition. So your query should look something like this:

```
$q->from('Contact c') 
  ->leftJoin('c.Activity a')
;

$subquery = $q->createSubquery()
    ->select("a1.contact_id, MAX(a1.date) a1.date")
    ->from("Activity a1")
    ->groupby("a1.contact_id")
;

$q->where('ROW (c.id, date) IN ('.$subquery->getDql().')')
  ->andWhere('a.activity_type_id = ?', $filterActivityTypeId)
;
```

Another example can be found here:

https://www.philipphoffmann.de/2012/08/29/a-bulletproof-pattern-for-creating-doctrine-subqueries-of-any-complexity/